# Programming arithmetic's

Tags: c++

So I need a program that just adds 2 numbers and adds,divides,multiplies and subtracts whatever

number the user inputs (in this case it'll be a float number)

So I came up with this code so far,

```
int main(void){

    float num1, num2, sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4;

    printf("Enter the first interger: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);

    printf("Enter the second integer: ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    printf("\n\n");

    //sums

    sum1 = (num1 + num2);
    printf("\n\t %.2f", sum1);

    sum2 = (num1 - num2);
    printf("\n\t %.2f", sum2);

    sum3 = (num1 * num2);
    printf("\n\t %.2f", sum3);

    sum4 = (num1 / num2);
    printf("\n\t %.2f", sum4);

    printf("\n\t %.2f", sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4); //print out each sum on a new line

    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");

}
```

And when I run it it runs perfectly fine but it only prints out the values as single numbers.. (hard to explain)..

For example what when somebody enters 10 and 10, the output is:

```
20

100

0

1
```

And what should be printed out is:

```
10+10 = 20

10*10 = 100

10-10 = 0

10/10 = 1
```

What do I need to add or change in order to achieve this?

Comment: print out each number, the symbol, the equal sign, and then the answer...

Comment: You never actually try to print "num1 + num2" etc. The compiler does exactly what you tell it to do (no more, no less), so if you don't tell it to print "num1 + num2" it's not going to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you labelled C++ I will do it in C++:. Every time you want to print a result, you have to specify all you want to print (otherwise the compiler cannot figure that out for you). The way of specific what you want to do is:

```
std::cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << sum1 << std::endl;
....
std::cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << " = " << sum2 << std::endl;
```

And so on. Do not forget to `#include<iostream>`

EDIT: just in case you need a printf()-based solution:

```
printf("\n\t %.2f + %.2f = %.2f", num1, num2, sum1);
```